# Setting up Multifactor Authentication in Microsoft Entra Admin Center

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have registered an app in the Microsoft Entra Admin Center. I have enrolled in the Microsoft Partner program and have an MPNID. I want to add my MPNID to my app to verify the publisher. I get an error message stating that I must use MFA to proceed. I cannot figure out how to enable MFA in the Entra Admin Center. If I go to Protection/Security Center/Multifactor Authentication it appears to require me to get a free premium trial to use this feature. I activated the free trial of MS Entrada ID P2. I found my way to Security/Conditional Access, which seems to be where one creates a policy for MFA. The Create New Policy button is greyed out, and beneath it is a link saying "Create your own policies . . . with Microsoft Entra ID Premium," which takes me back to the free trial sign-up. I'm in a loop. So, please, how do I add MFA to the the Microsoft Entra Admin Center so that I can add my MPNID to my app?

Comment: Can you paste the screenshots and include more details??Are you trying to enable MFA for your own account or for all users in your organization? could you please provide me with the exact error message you are receiving when trying to add your MPNID to your app

Comment: Thank you very much for your willingness to help.  I found the answer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/howto-identity-protection-configure-mfa-policy.  Regards, Paul

Answer (score 0):

> Posting the solution as Answer for community benefits reference to this [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/identity-protection/howto-identity-protection-configure-mfa-policy).

Note that: To create conditional access policy **Azure Active Directory Premium P1 or P2** license is required.

Sign in to [**Microsoft Entra admin center**](https://entra.microsoft.com/#home) with Security Administrator or Global Admin role.

*Click on Protection -> Identity Protection -> MFA registration policy -> Multifactor authentication registration policy*

Based on your requirement select All users or select individuals and groups and enable the policy enforcement and save

[image]

Now when the user signs in, **the user is prompted for registering MFA** like below:

[image]